# How to create a mysql view in Magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2, database, view

Is it possible to create a mysql view in Magento 2 just like we create table in InstallScheme.php. I want to create a view which will be a join of multiple table with selected columns.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but unfortunately, it requires you to use plain SQL. At least this is how Magento itself does it in the rather newish inventory project (see https://github.com/magento/inventory/blob/40e199b82fd2e1cdd07541f856aa45a8a2e40fc3/InventoryCatalog/Setup/Patch/Schema/CreateLegacyStockStatusView.php#L68-L83):

```
$sql = "CREATE
        SQL SECURITY INVOKER
        VIEW {$viewToLegacyIndex}
          AS
            SELECT
            DISTINCT    
              legacy_stock_status.product_id,
              legacy_stock_status.website_id,
              legacy_stock_status.stock_id,
              legacy_stock_status.qty quantity,
              legacy_stock_status.stock_status is_salable,
              product.sku
            FROM {$legacyStockStatusTable} legacy_stock_status
              INNER JOIN {$productTable} product
                ON legacy_stock_status.product_id = product.entity_id;";
$this->schemaSetup->getConnection()->query($sql);
```

Hence, I doubt that there is a better way in Magento to create views :-(